# Removing part of in-memory cache values in .net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, caching

During working of app I add/get items to/form Concurrent Dictionary. I have in every of them a property - timestamp. When I use specific item from dictionary its timestamp will update. After 5 minutes I want to remove a few the oldest items.

Right now I use TimedHostedService (which implements IHostedService) and in the dictionary keep object with timestamp and update it manually.

**Is there easier approach for that?**

Comment: Is [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) what you want?

Comment: I have never used it and as I'm reading about it I'm not sure if it fits to my needs

Comment: Memory cache supports time-based expiry of items, so it sounds like it would fit your needs to me.

Comment: I disagree because I do not want to remove specific item after some time but remove e.g. 5 the oldest items in collection after every 5 minutes.